# How to create a shared object library (*.so) with mysql connector?

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, compilation, shared-libraries

I have written a very simple application in C, for which I would like to have a connection with MySQL database. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>

void runtime_tile_opt(void); 


int main(void) {
    runtime_tile_opt();
    return 0;
}


void runtime_tile_opt() {
    printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

}
```

If i run `gcc -o runtime $(mysql_config --cflags) runtime.c $(mysql_config --libs)`, everything works fine, all libraries seemed to be properly linked, and if I run the executable, I get a legitimate-looking output:

```
MySQL client version: 5.5.49
```

However, I would like to make a shared library out of it. So I'm trying to create an object file, with `-fPIC` flag:

```
gcc -c -fPIC runtime.c $(mysql_config --cflags) -o runtime.o $(mysql_config --libs)
```

The outputs of `mysql_config --libs` `mysql_config --cflags` are:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl
-I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing    -g -DNDEBUG
```

Finally, I create my `.so`:

```
gcc runtime.o -shared -o runtime.so
```

All of the above went with no errors whatsoever. However, some library is not linked apparently, since when I run a file with this plugin loaded, I get:

```
/home/michal/thesis/Drafts/runtime/runtime.so: undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'
```

This function is defined in the header files I included. I'm not very experienced with gcc, but I look at it and it looks as though I linked what I had to link. Any ideas where did I fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to pass the correct `-l` flags to the compiler when creating a shared library. They should be the same flags you pass when creating a binary, i.e.

```
gcc -shared -o runtime.so $(mysql_config --cflags) runtime.o $(mysql_config --libs)
```

Note that the order of options is important! First pass all options, then all files and lastly libraries (`-l...` operands).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what was missing. Thank you sir!